# (Groovy @ 12.04) E: Package 'libtbb-dev' has no installation candidate

Tags: ros, rosdep-install, source, package, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Am installing ROS Groovy (from source) on a Tablet, whose Kernel is armv7l.
When running the command:
$ rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro groovy -y
Items install up until:
executing command [sudo apt-get install -y libtbb-dev]
as it shows the following error:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package libtbb-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source
E: Package 'libtbb-dev' has no installation candidate
ERROR: the following rosdeps failed to install
apt: command [sudo apt-get install -y libtbb-dev] failed

Any suggestions? If not needed, what other rosdeps exist after this one that the device did not get a chance to install?

Thanks...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51742/(groovy-@-12.04)-e:-package-%27libtbb-dev%27-has-no-installation-candidate/) by [amrivera](https://answers.ros.org/users/3700/amrivera/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2013-01-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

TBB packages are not built for ARM architectures (not sure if that is even possible/supported).

You can however pass the robust option (-r) to rosdep, and it will continue installing the other dependencies if some packages were not found:

`rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro groovy -yr`

So no need to revert back to installing all dependencies by hand.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Ruess](https://answers.ros.org/users/890/felix-ruess/) with karma: 118 on 2013-01-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [corrosion](https://answers.ros.org/users/3962/corrosion/) on 2013-04-05**:
What will break if libtbb-dev and collada-dom-dev failed to install?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried the same thing on the gumstix and had to find out that rosdep will not work for a not x86 or 64 Bit system because the packages have not been built for your architecture. I went the hard way and installed every dependency by hand. This will by far not be the only missing package!

Kai

---

Originally posted by [kalectro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3904/kalectro/) with karma: 1554 on 2013-01-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1